# Pass test category name at runtime using Selenium with NUnit framework

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testing, runtime, nunit

I have to run my Selenium with NUnit suite on different environments with different URL's, however there is no CI/CD pipeline. And because of that, I have devised a method in the test base class in the [Setup] section which will check the Test Category Passed. And if that is true, then the respective URL will be set before each test case is executed.

The challenge I am facing is that I need to pass the Category in each test case every time I need to change its execution from the dev environment to the SIT environment or UAT environment. Is there a way we can parametrize this or pass the Test Category at runtime?

This is the condition set in setup section and the browser initialization.

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUpTest()
{
    if (HasTestCategory("SIT"))
    {
        _url = "SIT-URL";
    }
    else if (HasTestCategory("Dev"))
    {
        _url = "DEV-URL";`
    }

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--headless=new");
            options.AddArgument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.AddArgument("--incognito");
            options.AddArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");

            Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}
```

This is the HasTestCategory method:

```
private bool HasTestCategory(string testCategory)
{
    var testCategories = (IList)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Category"];
    return testCategories.Contains(testCategory);
}
```

I tried using TestCaseSource as part of NUnit framework but of no help. Also, could not get enough help from the articles shared on net for NUnit. However, there is for TestNG.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the command used to run the tests?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Have updated the setup method with the driver initializations that I do. Do let me know if you intended more information.